# Connecting Java-Spring application war to AWS RDS Oracle DB instance

Tags: amazon-rds

I have an AWS EC2 windows instance and have my application war running there on Tomcat server. Following is my db.properties file -

```
driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@whitelabeldb.cyor6spheonu.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1521:ORCL
username=admin
password=pwc12345
initialSize=2
maxConnections=10
maxIdle=1
minIdle=1
```

My application-context file is reading this properties file. When i try to hit any service of my application i get the below error -

```
Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

I tried manually adding the ojdbc6.jar in the lib of the WAR file. By doing that, i stop getting any error in the logs but a 404 in postman. I cannot change the complete architecture of my application and convert into spring boot or something because it is a big application.
Please help me with some solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add ojdbc7 jar to the pom.xml and download the dependency. If not able to add it, try to dowload from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc7/12.1.0.2 and add it to build path.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```